# ArrowDB dashboard upload photo to user

Tags: appcelerator, photo

when I upload a photo using the arrowdb dashboard on https://platform.appcelerator.com

Cloud.Users.query only shows the photo_id

but whne I created a new user using the dashboard and attached a phot it is showing in the Cloud.Users.query

eg . photo uploaded after user created

```
{
"id": "563019f18cb04aede69e2111",
"first_name": "store1",
"last_name": "123",
"created_at": "2015-10-28T00:42:25+0000",
"updated_at": "2016-01-22T08:59:44+0000",
"external_accounts": [],
"confirmed_at": "2015-10-28T00:42:25+0000",
"username": "user",
"admin": "false",
"stats": {
    "photos": {
        "total_count": 0
    },
    "storage": {
        "used": 0
    }
},
"photo_id": "56a1dc083a654d090d126792",
"friend_counts": {
    "requests": 0,
    "friends": 0
}
```

}

eg. photo uploaded while creating user

```
  {
"id": "56a1f0333a65234234390d7",
"first_name": "qqqq",
"last_name": "wwwe",
"created_at": "2016-01-22T09:02:43+0000",
"updated_at": "2016-01-22T09:07:18+0000",
"external_accounts": [],
"confirmed_at": "2016-01-22T09:02:43+0000",
"username": "qwe",
"admin": "false",
"stats": {
    "photos": {
        "total_count": 0
    },
    "storage": {
        "used": 0
    }
},
"photo": {
    "id": "56a1f0333a654d090d0390d8",
    "filename": "userPhoto.jpg",
    "size": 25394,
    "md5": "e20f4fcadf6cde9fccfb458dd11951d4",
    "created_at": "2016-01-22T09:02:43+0000",
    "updated_at": "2016-01-22T09:02:43+0000",
    "processed": true,
    "urls": {
        "original": "https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/storage-platform.cloud.appcelerator.com/xmqh1djNEIChtQFP6d37HNH5DQNCXQoX/photos/51/d4/56a1f0333a654d090d0390d9/userPhoto_original.jpg"
    },
    "content_type": "image/jpeg",
    "user": {
        "id": "56a1f0333a65234234390d7",
        "first_name": "qqqq",
        "last_name": "wwwe",
        "created_at": "2016-01-22T09:02:43+0000",
        "updated_at": "2016-01-22T09:07:18+0000",
        "external_accounts": [],
        "confirmed_at": "2016-01-22T09:02:43+0000",
        "username": "qwe",
        "admin": "false",
        "stats": {
            "photos": {
                "total_count": 0
            },
            "storage": {
                "used": 0
            }
        },
        "photo_id": "56a1f0333a654d090d0390d8",
        "friend_counts": {
            "requests": 0,
            "friends": 0
        }
    }
},
"friend_counts": {
    "requests": 0,
    "friends": 0
}
}
```

basically the user which had photo uploaded during creation shows this extra info

```
"photo": {
    "id": "56a1f0333a654d090d0390d8",
    "filename": "userPhoto.jpg",
    "size": 25394,
    "md5": "e20f4fcadf6cde9fccfb458dd11951d4",
    "created_at": "2016-01-22T09:02:43+0000",
    "updated_at": "2016-01-22T09:02:43+0000",
    "processed": true,
    "urls": {
        "original": "https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/storage-platform.cloud.appcelerator.com/xmqh1djNEIChtQFP6d37HNH5DQNCXQoX/photos/51/d4/56a1f0333a654d090d0390d9/userPhoto_original.jpg"
    },
    "content_type": "image/jpeg",
    "user": {
        "id": "56a1f0333a65234234390d7",
        "first_name": "qqqq",
        "last_name": "wwwe",
        "created_at": "2016-01-22T09:02:43+0000",
        "updated_at": "2016-01-22T09:07:18+0000",
        "external_accounts": [],
        "confirmed_at": "2016-01-22T09:02:43+0000",
        "username": "qwe",
        "admin": "false",
        "stats": {
            "photos": {
                "total_count": 0
            },
            "storage": {
                "used": 0
            }
        },
```

Comment: It looks like you've found a bug. Please check if this is a known issue at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org). If it's not, create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Answer (score 1):

I've been experiencing also that kind of problem, plus I've noticed that the images won't show up from the ArrowDB user interface (not sure if related).
The API returns only an empty object when you query the model:
`photo: {}`

I've been creating a ticket for the ArrowDB user interface https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/API-1277.

sachinmw did you create a ticket for the initial problem yet?

A workaround could be to use the `photo_id` and run another separate query to retrieve the photo model but this is not good for network optimisation purposes.

---

**EDIT**

Ok after dealing with Appcelerator directly about having an empty `photo: {}` Object return the answer is pretty simple:

Whenever you use the `query()` function like [`Cloud.Objects.query()`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/arrowdb/latest/#!/api/CustomObjects-method-query) from `ti.cloud` on any ArrowDB object, there is a parameter called `response_json_depth` which is set to `1` by default and will only return one level of the JSON Object returned by the API.

Without touching that parameter I was seeing:

```
{
    "Vehicle": [
        {
            "name": "foo",
            "photo: {}
        }
    ]
}
```

By setting `response_json_depth` to `3` I managed to have:

```
{
    "Vehicle": [
        {
            "name": "foo",
            "photo: {
                "urls": {
                    "original": "http://bar.com"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Hope that will help someone. The also applies for the [`Cloud.Objects.show()`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/arrowdb/latest/#!/api/CustomObjects-method-show) method for any ArrowDB object.